# how to get single value from group_concat query

Tags: php

[i am getting these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmOv.png)

[but i need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwbPa.png)

How to get seperate value for quiz name ?

```
query=select userquiz.id,userquiz.user_id,userss.username,quiz.quiz_name,GROUP_CONCAT(userquiz.quiz_id) as 'quiz_id',GROUP_CONCAT(quiz.quiz_name) as 'quiz_name' from userquiz join userss on userss.id=userquiz.user_id join quiz on quiz.quiz_id=userquiz.quiz_id group by user_id;

    $filter_query = $query . ' ' . 'LIMIT ' . $start . ', ' . $limit 
    . '';
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
// print_r($query);
$statement->execute();
$total_data = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($filter_query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$total_filter_data = $statement->rowCount();

$output = '
<label> Total Records :- ' . $total_data . '</label>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:40px";>
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Quizname</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  '; 
if ($total_data > 0) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $output .= '
    <tr>
      <td>' . $row["username"] . '</td>
      <td><button type=" button" style="background-color:maroon; border: #4685A9;" class="btn btn-success"">' . $row["quiz_name"] . '</td>
      <td><button type=" button" style="background-color:red; border: #4685A9;" class="btn btn-primary dltbtn" data-id="' . $row["user_id"] . '"> DELETE</button>
      <button type=" button" style="background-color:orange; border: #4685A9;" class="btn btn-primary editbtn" data-eid="' . $row["user_id"] . '">Assign Quiz</button></td>
    </tr>
      ';
    }
```

this is how i am fetching the values
i need to make quiz as button so that can be deleted

Comment: just add a filter condition in your query

Comment: i already did can u help me with posting the changes below down
thank you in advance

Comment: Add a `where` clause please